# MVCScaffolding ' Invoke-ScaffoldTemplate : Error HRESULT E_FAIL COMException '?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

All of a sudden I am getting the following from my MVCScaffolding command in PMC :

```
Invoke-ScaffoldTemplate : Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
At line:1 char:23
+ param($c, $a) return . <<<<  $c @a
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-ScaffoldTemplate], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.InvokeScaffoldTemplateCmdlet
```

Haven't changed anything much since last ran successfully, and this error doesn't give me much  info.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh ha. For me this was a ridiculously simple one, just a scary error. Not sure why Google gave me nothing on this...

I had added the solution to source control in TFS, and the file the T4 was trying to edit was not checked out ! So...

1. Simply check out the target file
2. Or even better, use the **Set-IsCheckedOut** as per [Useful T4Scaffolding cmdlets for use in custom scaffolders](http://mvcscaffolding.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4Scaffolding%27s%20cmdlets%20for%20use%20in%20custom%20scaffolders)

Simplesh !